# "Form region" for calendar views in outlook add-in

Tags: calendar, outlook, office365, add-in, outlook-addin

Overview: I would like to show a "form region" when calendar is selected in Outlook. I also would like to show some custom HTML content in the reading pane (or any pane like task pane adjacent to main calendar pane).

Questions:

1. Are API add-ins allowed for Calendar views in Outlook?
2. Are & custom form regions allowed for Calendar views in Outlook?
3. Would it be possible to show Custom form region here in Calendar's reading pane when no specific time is selected in the calendar?
4. Would it be possible to show Custom form region here in Calendar's reading pane when specific appointment type is selected in the calendar?

[image: Read Pane in Calendar view of Outlook]

Answer (score 1):

Create a task pane instead - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb296010.aspx.

Takes panes can be displayed both in explorers (that is what you need) and inspectors (similar to form regions).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's currently not possible to open an Outlook Add-In in 'Calendar/meeting view' using the 'new' office add-in model. It's only possible to open it in Mail Read or Compose mode and Appointment/meeting Read or Compose mode where a single item is opened. Maybe you could create a UserVoice for this?

[OfficeDev UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com)